# Docker error: entrypoint permission denied

Tags: dockerfile, permission-denied

I'm trying to build a docker image where the entrypoint can run without the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app\": permission denied": unknown.
```

my OS: Windows 10

Dockerfile content:

```
ARG GO_VERSION=1.11
FROM golang:${GO_VERSION}-alpine AS builder
RUN mkdir /user && \
    echo 'nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/:' > /user/passwd && \
    echo 'nobody:x:65534:' > /user/group
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0 GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/XXXXmyrepoXXXX
COPY ./ ./
RUN go build \
    -installsuffix 'static' \
    -o /app .


FROM scratch AS final
COPY --from=builder /user/group /user/passwd /etc/
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=builder /app /app
EXPOSE 8080
USER nobody:nobody
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

How should I change the Dockerfile, it should work as well as it does here https://medium.com/@pierreprinetti/the-go-1-11-dockerfile-a3218319d191? There are literally no changes.

Comment: what happens if you use `USER root`

Comment: user root does not exist in the "AS final" image: `docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that i did not go build the correct path.