# Running a docker Image of Golang failed, with error 'starting container process caused: exec: "/path": permission denied'

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I build a `Go` docker image from docker file successfully, but `docker run -p port:port --name imagename imageid` gives me `permission denied` error.

This is my docker file

```
FROM golang:1.17.2-alpine3.13 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -o app

FROM alpine:3.7

COPY --from=build /app /usr/local/bin/go_webhooks

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/go_webhooks

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/go_webhooks"]
```

I tried using `chmod` but still could not solve it.

The actual error message is:

```sh
docker run -p 8000:8000 --name go_webs3 d5f30e8f9703 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
"/usr/local/bin/go_webhooks": permission denied: unknown. 
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A past [similar error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541211/docker-error-entrypoint-permission-denied) pointed out to a `go build` issue.

But in your case, copying a *folder* to `/usr/local/bin/go_webhooks` would make `go_webhooks` a *folder*.

```
WORKDIR /app
# means /app is a folder
```

You cannot directly execute a folder.
Your Entrypoint needs to reference an executable inside that folder.

You might needs to copy the built file inside /app:

```
COPY --from=build /app/app /usr/local/bin/go_webhooks
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. @VonC its a dumb mistake from my side try to copy a folder instead of a executable file

Comment: @RoshanTwanabasu No problem. The `DIR` in `WORKDIR app` was the clue I needed.